# Chart showing year progression correctly, but not showing proper data per year

Tags: python, pandas, charts, seaborn

OK... so this time I am actually asking for help with an item that is homework related.  But only because I am out of thoughts on what I am doing incorrectly.
I am creating two charts, one shows the number of movies released per year between 1960 and 2015, the other will show the population of the USA between the same two years.

The chart for the number of movies comes out perfect... exactly how it should.  The chart for the Population shows the correct progression of years along the bottom, but the population shows all '1's.

Here is the code I have now.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import numpy as np
import collections as coll 
import unicodecsv
import datetime as dt
import seaborn as sbn

%matplotlib inline


#load Data from CSV and make readable
USAPop = pd.read_csv('USAPop2.csv')
USAPop.rename(columns = {'POPTOTUSA647NWDB': 'Population'},inplace = True) #CHanges ungainly column 
name
USAPop['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(USAPop['DATE']).dt.year #Converts the full date into year only

print(USAPop.head()) #looking at the data to see where I might be going wrong


#USAPop = USAPop['DATE']



plt.figure(figsize = (15,8));
sbn.countplot(USAPop);
plt.xticks(rotation = 90);
plt.xlabel('1960 - 2015', fontsize = 10);
plt.ylabel('No. Movies released');
```

- Updated the above code to reflect that I had included what I thought were the correct library imports.

The result I get with this code is:

[image]

I am pretty sure that you are going to show me something that I will slap my head in embarrassment over... but like I said in another post, be gentle, I am still learning and I am only asking because I am lost.

Per request:
Print results for Before and After conversion from full date to year only:

[image]

Comment: Can you show a small sample of your population data before and after conversion? More than likely the problem is there.

Comment: Added the requested info.  I saw no difference other than what was expected.  The year is in DT format for year, so it was not changed  to an unusable datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, `countplot` is not right choice here, it will just count the number of occurrences of the `DATE` in your dataframe. Here is an example:

```
#test df
print(df)
   DATE  Population
0  1961        1000
1  1962        5000
2  1963        7000
3  1964        9000
4  1965       10000
5  1966       15000
6  1967       20000
7  1968       30000
8  1969       32000

sns.countplot(df['DATE'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

You need a simple `barplot`, which can be simply made using `pandas`:

```
df.plot.bar(x='DATE')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Or

```
df.groupby('DATE').sum().plot.bar()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or if you like `seaborn` barplot:

```
sns.barplot(x='DATE',y = 'Population', data=df)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Added an answer. Let me know if it works for you. If it does please upvote and accept/check-mark the answer.

Comment: OK... So that I understand this...

The way I WAS doing it, was simply saying 'You have 1 occurrence of 1961, you have 1 occurrence of 1962... and so on.

The way you are explaining, it what I was doing incorrectly is using the wrong method for counting the data for the graph.  

Going forward, the proper way is to use the barplot (x , y) so that I am defining what each data set should be.  

Ugh... now that I am going back and looking at the myriad of attempts I had been making, I see that I looked that those and opted not to use them because they seemed wrong to me.  

Thanks all.

Comment: Yes, if you want to see how population is increasing with number of years. Barplot is a perfect choice. I assume that's what you wanted.

Comment: I used the seaborn option you showed, since the rest of my charts are already in seaborn.  This was the only one I was having issues with.   

Thanks again to you and the others that offered advice.  Much appreciated.